# Как должен выглядеть тест к данной функции?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-сервер, jest

Только начинаю изучать тестирование. Как должен выглядеть тест к данной функции? Использую `jest`.

```js
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        await sequelize.sync();
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут нечего тестировать - стандартные функции, стандартной библиотеки оттестировали разработчики (надеюсь), перед выкатыванием релиза

Comment: Вам нужно лишь правильно (в рамках вашей стратегии) отреагировать на возможные ошибки (исключения).